# Typescript Eclipse plugin problems and questions

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, typescript

Having some trouble configuring eclipse with typescript. I've tried both the Typescript and TypEcs plugins. I've been trying to set up the project AngularJSWithTypeScriptDemo from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888764/Getting-started-with-TypeScript-in-AngularJS-appli
I've used TypeScript in Intellij with no problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be available with the free community version.

When I used the TypeScript plugin from http://eclipse-update.palantir.com/eclipse-typescript/ it did not automatically compile my typescript files into javascript. I didn't see any way to configure it to do that.

So I uninstalled TypeScript and installed TypEcs to see if it had better configuration. It gave errors like "Cannot find namespace ng" indicating it could not find the d.ts files in the project. I did not see how to configure that as well.  I also had some errors when I clicked on module names in the TypeScript outlline.

So I uninstalled TypEcs and went back to TypeScript. Now I've got 3557 errors in lib.d.ts "Duplicate identifier '$1'" in lib.d.ts. So at least it TypeScript finds the .d.ts file. It wasn't generating this error on the first go round so maybe there is a problem with the other installation.

Any help would be appreciated as to which is the preferred plug-in, how to get it to automatically compile. How to configure to find the d.ts definitions and now how to get rid of these errors. There doesn't seem to be much documentation with either of these plugins.

Comment: Did you try https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be appreciated as to which is the preferred plug-in, how to get it to automatically compile. How to configure to find the d.ts definitions and now how to get rid of these errors. There doesn't seem to be much documentation with either of these plugins.

Recommend you give atom-typescript a go : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript Compile on save is a very important and maintained feature for us.

Answer (score 0):

With most plugins you must install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your dev machine and point to it in somewhere the in the Eclipse preferences (which updates some hidden Eclipse config file). It works like this:

```
.ts file modified -> node.js tsc -> .js files
```

I made the [Eclipse palantir plugin](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript) work, I suppose most other plugins are similar.